# tabs navigation for single page website that return to the previously opened tab by pressing "back button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

i'm working on a new projet and i'm using tabs as pages of the site with jquery.
I arrive at a point where I need the "browser back button" to return to the previously opened tab. Is there a solution for that?

```html
<a data-content="page1">1</a> 
<a data-content="page2">2</a>
<a data-content="page3">3</a>

    <ul class="cd-tabs-content">

    <li data-content="page1">page1</li>
    <li data-content="page2">page2</li>
    <li data-content="page3">page3</li>

    <ul>
```

Comment: Store the previous tab id in the global variable and on clicking the back, load it from there and show the previous tab using jquery.

Comment: thanks, do you have any example?